# ".append" and "+" semantic difference inside of functions

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble to understand what is the difference between these 3 examples.

```
#example1    
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list1= list1+[6]
list1.append(1000)
print("Example 1: ", list1)

# example 2
def f(j):
  j= j + [6]
  j.append(1000)

list2 = [1,2,3,4]
f(list2)
print("Example 2: ", list2)

# example 3
def f(j):
  j.append(1000)
  j= j +[6]

list3 = [1,2,3,4]
f(list3)
print("Example 2: ", list3)
```

**Output:**

[image: Python Output]

The **first one** I did some simple addition using (+) and (.append), it worked fine.

The **second one** I created a function. I guess I understood the results. In my opinion, it remained the same because the changes that I've done in the original list were only made locally, so, after the function had finished, the original list have remained the same. Am I right?

The **third one** I can't understand. Because it is exactly like the second one, I've just changed the order of the elements, however the output is completely different.

Comment: `.append()` modifies an existing list.  `+` creates a new list.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your output.  In particular,  images of text are not acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example 2 creates a *new* list with `j = j + [6]`, and the only reference to the that list is the local variable `j`, so the change is not visible after `f` returns.

Example 3 appends the value to the *original* list referenced by `j`, which `list3` still refers to.

Comment: You might want to mention that `+=` is like `append`, it modifies the list in place. So he could write `j += [6]`